# Can I use multienum and enumitem together?

Tags: lists, enumitem

I'd like to use some of the features available with the `enumitem` package with the `multienumerate` environments used by the `multienum` package.  Is there a way to do this?

I'm looking to use the series abilities of `enumitem` with the vertically-aligned multi-column enumerated lists of `multienum`.  Example below, although I can't really call it a MWE because it doesn't work as-is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicols, multienum, enumitem}

\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, series=myseries]
    \item foo
    \item bar
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{multienumerate}[resume*=myseries]
    \mitemxx{foo}{bar}
    \mitemxx{etc}{etc}
  \end{multienumerate}

\end{document}
```

Is this possible?  Or do I just need to find another solution?

Comment: You may be interested in `tasks` package which offers multi column lists.

Comment: No compatibility exists and it would require a complete redesign of [`multienum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multenum) to interface with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Comment: `enumitem` also supports resuming items.

Comment: @percusse I was assuming that `multienum` doesn't and that's the issue?

Comment: @percusse, Yes, as far as I have been able to tell multienum doesn't do resuming.

Comment: @HarishKumar, thanks! I hadn't heard of the `tasks` package.  Might be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: My mistake. I totally misread the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tasks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\settasks{
  label=\textbf{\arabic*.}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}
  \task foo
  \task bar
\end{tasks}

\begin{tasks}[resume](2)
  \task foo
  \task bar
  \task etc
  \task etc
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]